# Exporting Resharper Inspection Results for Incoming Calls?

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

In Resharper, Inspection Results - Incoming Calls

Is it possible to export the results to Text,Html or XML?

There is an export button with drop down for Text,Html and XML. But clicking it does not bring up the Reharper save to file to dialog.

Highlighting and pressing ctrl + C also does not copy the values.

Is this a bug in Resharper, or this feature doesn't work in in Reshaper Evaluation mode?

PS: Just notice export seems not to work for File Structure either, either I am missing a setting or this is a bug or it is not enabled for Evaluation Mode.

I have tested this on 2 separate machines, one with fresh installation on windows and VS2013, with same results.

Also pressing '+' to expand all for all the incoming calls does not cause the all the nodes to expand, still have to manually click every node, is this a common behavior for everyone or just in the evaluation mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the export issue is a bug. I've reported it here - [RSRP-440597](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-440597). You can log on, vote and track it.

The expand all behaviour is a little unintuitive. It's actually expanding all items that have previously been expanded, rather than expanding anything that hasn't yet been searched for. I can understand why - this could be massively slow as it recursively works out usages for all items, but it's not obvious that it works like this. There's an issue that already tracks this - [RSRP-414445](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-414445).